# How to remove rows containing nan in .fits file with Python?

Tags: python, nan, astropy

I tried to remove rows where nan occurs in an astropy table like so

```
a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=1)]
```

but i get following error-code:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to remove rows where any column in that row has a `NaN`. That would be like so:

```
In [17]: t = Table([[1.0, np.nan, 3.0], [10, 20, np.nan]])

In [18]: t
Out[18]: 
<Table length=3>
  col0    col1 
float64 float64
------- -------
    1.0    10.0
    nan    20.0
    3.0     nan

In [19]: bad = np.logical_or.reduce([np.isnan(col) for col in t.itercols()])

In [20]: bad
Out[20]: array([False,  True,  True])

In [21]: t[~bad]
Out[21]: 
<Table length=1>
  col0    col1 
float64 float64
------- -------
    1.0    10.0
```

Comment: This seems to do the job! however, i started out with 964506 rows and now I have only 351 left. 
How do i remove rows for only certain col.names containing nan?

Comment: Change `[np.isnan(col) for col in t.itercols()]` to `[np.isnan(t[name]) for name in names]` where `names` is your list of columns that should be filtered for `nan`.

Comment: BTW @CecilieHansen if this is the right answer can you upvote it and/or check it as the right answer? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What do the NaNs look like in the table/array? The error you are reporting suggests a mixture of numbers and characters. If you are reading a table with pandas you could use pandas.dropna() which worked great for me in the past.

Comment: Instead of positive numbers, it says 'nan' in my table. I think this is because values that are negative are made into 'nan'. But I want to remove them completely and restart the indexing. I want to post a picture here, but I dont think i can. 
I also tried pandas.nan() but i get the following error code: 
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Can you supply some code where you read in the table?

Comment: The question is about astropy Table not pandas DataFrame.

Comment: The question is about a numpy error msg.

Comment: This is how i load in the data. I removed the pathname as it is very long:
data_farmer = open_cat('/User....data_farmer.fits',hdu=1)